# Colocar el valor una variable de javascript en un textarea

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día me gustaría depositar el resultado que me arroja una variable de javascript en un textarea, de antemano gracias!

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "La geolocalizaci&oacuten no es soportada por este navegador.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería funcionar. Simplemente tienes que llamar a la función `getLocation`.

Ten en cuenta que el navegador solicitará permiso al usuario para obtener la localización y deberías tener en cuenta la posibilidad de que el usuario no consintiera.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, noPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "La geolocalizaci&oacuten no es soportada por este navegador.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "\nLongitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
} 

function noPosition(positionError){
  console.log(positionError);
}

getLocation();
```

```css
#demo{
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu código lo veo bien como tal, lo único que te falta hacer es ejecutar/llamar a la función que captura la geolocalización `getLocation();`

**NOTA:** un salto de línea dentro de un contenido de texto lo haces con `\n` y no con `<br>`

Te dejo el código funcional:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "La geolocalizaci&oacuten no es soportada por este navegador.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
    "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
} 

getLocation();
```

```html
<textarea id="demo" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: excelente, gracias por el aporte!

Comment: django, considera marcar como solucionada tu pregunta, dandole en el signo de visto bueno a la respuesta que ha satisfecho lo preguntado.